# Using AppLocker without Constrained Language Mode

Tags: powershell, group-policy, applocker

I would appreciate it if someone can assist me in making Constrained Language not be a pain on Win11 Pro 22H2. I prefer to use the terminal in non-admin mode, and despite my PowerShell profile being authenticode signed and an Applocker policy made for it, it does not allow it to run outside CLM. The environmental variable to bypass it is not working.

Can't source my profile script in CLM. Running my session as admin all the time is not desirable to me from a security perspective.